# how to create a new node with an Image field using services module Drupal 7 testing with POSTER extension?

Tags: web-services, rest, drupal-7, poster

I am trying to create a new node using services module and testing with POSTER extension of google crome.
This node has custom image field, now facing trouble with; how to pass values for the image field.

Node Type: 'article'
Node fields: 'title', 'body', 'article_image'

Answer (score 2):

You need two steps to achieve this. First upload the file and get the fid and then you post the article with fid included.

step 1 example:

```
{
    "filename": "arkadikos_default_image.jpg",
    "target_uri": "pictures/arkadikos_default_image.jpg",
    "filemime": "image/jpg",
    "file": "/9j/4QAYRXh..",
    "filesize": "29000"
}
```

step 2 example:

```
{
    "title": "My title",
    "type": "article",
    "language": "el",
  "body" : {
        "und": [
            {
                "value": "test text"
            } ]
  },
  "field_image": { 
        "und": [ 
          { 
            "fid": "1364" 
          } 
        ]
  }

}
```

Comment: Also, File in step 1 ("file": "/9j/4QAYRXh..") is uploaded in base64 encoding.